# How do I Turn This Into An if statement?

Tags: php, loop, child-pages, 500-internal-error

PHP noob here. I've got this query I've written to get the information of all child pages of the page you're currently on:

```
               <?php
                    $pages = get_pages('child_of=1015&sort_column=post_title');
                    $count = 0;

                    foreach($pages as $page)
                    { ?>
                        <div class="position-info"><h4><a href="<?php echo get_page_link($page->ID) ?>"><?php echo $page->post_title ?></a></h4></div>
                    <?php
                    }
                ?>
```

But I don't know the correct syntax to turn this into an if statement, followed by an else statement so I can say "There's no content here. Check back later." Or something like that.

This query is inside of the page's main loop.

Can any PHP masters out there help?

Comment: We ask that questions demonstrate research and effort on the part of the asker - in this case [the `get_pages()` documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages#Return) and  [the documentation on PHP conditionals](http://php.net/manual/en/language.control-structures.php) adequately answers your question. Please review "[ask]" in our [help] to learn more about what comprises questions that are a good fit for the WordPress Development community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code I got working, thanks Manu!

```
<?php
                    // Vars
                    $pages = get_pages('child_of=1015&sort_column=post_title');
                    $count = 0;

                    if (!empty($pages)) {
                      foreach($pages as $page) { ?>
                        <div class="position-info"><h4><a href="<?php echo get_page_link($page->ID) ?>"><?php echo $page->post_title ?></a></h4></div>
                    <?php
                    }
                    } else {
                      echo '<div class="position-info"><h4>Bummer! Looks like we&rsquo;re fresh out of internships. Check back often!</div>';
                    }
                ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer from an older PHP noob:

```
<?php

$pages = get_pages('child_of=1015&sort_column=post_title');
$count = 0;

if (!empty($pages)) {
  foreach($pages as $page) {
    // show stuff
  } // end foreach
} else {
  echo '<p>There’s no content here. Check back later.</p>';
}
?>
```

Comment: I'm getting a 500 Server Error with that above. I think it has to do with how the else statement starts. My PHP syntax colors aren't jiving in Sublime with that.

Comment: It's probably because of a forgotten opening or closing <?php or ?> at the wrong place ... i forgot one there when simplifying your code.